# verb+方 particle rules when preceded by more than one noun

Tags: particles, particle-の, english-to-japanese

When using verb+方, does the rule of converting a に or を particle to の only apply to noun closest to verb+方 or does it apply farther?

For example, if I want to say

> I want to know how to turn a screenshot into an emoji.

Do I say

> スクリーンショット**を**絵文字のし方を知りたいです。

or do I say

> スクリーンショット**の**絵文字のし方を知りたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, スクリーンショット**を**絵文字のし方 is ungrammatical. し方 works as a normal noun, rather than a verb phrase followed by the noun 方, and therefore doesn’t take an object with を like that.

スクリーンショット**の**絵文字のし方 is a grammatical noun phrase, where the noun し方 has two modifiers, both ending with の. However, its meaning is ambiguous, and therefore, you should avoid this structure and consider modifying a noun with a verb phrase, like スクリーンショットを絵文字にする方法, instead.

In general, a modifier with の seems to sound unambiguous and natural if the original particle is either (1) が to indicate the subject of the verb, (2) を to indicate the direct object of the verb, or (3) に to indicate a destination with a motion verb. As long as these conditions are satisfied, a noun phrase can have more than one modifier with の.

For example, the following sound completely natural.

> 彼女の字の書き方 (from 彼女**が**字**を**書く)

> 彼の自転車の乗り方 (from 彼**が**自転車**に**乗る)

These are precisely the cases when the meaning of the original sentence is understood even if the particles are omitted. While whether or not 乗る should be categorized as a “motion verb” may be debatable, 「彼、自転車乗る」 is definitely understood with no ambiguity.

Omitting に doesn’t always work, however. For example, 「スクリーンショット、絵文字する」 sounds broken, and this is probably why スクリーンショットの絵文字のし方 sounds unnatural. In another example, 「彼女、プレゼントあげる」 would be most likely understood as a colloquial form of 彼女**が**プレゼントをあげる, rather than 彼女**に**プレゼントをあげる, and therefore, this に should not be omitted if the latter is meant. Therefore, 彼女 is the giver in 彼女のプレゼントのあげ方, not the recipient.

By the way, this に could be converted into a modifier with への. For example, 彼女**への**プレゼントのあげ方 sounds natural. In the case of your example, the verb should be changed from する to another with a clearer sense of “change”, as in スクリーンショットの絵文字への変え方.